# Does AWS Cloud9 Preview Tunnel affect cookies?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, cookies, cloud9

I've got a react.js website running on an AWS EC2 VM with no issues, but now I'm trying to set up a secondary VM for development. We don't need this other VM to actually host the website publicly, we just want to be able to test UI. We're using the Cloud9 IDE for both VMs, so we figured we'd use the Cloud9 Preview tunnel, but I've been encountering issues with this.

Despite running the exact same code on both VMs, the one that is connected to the preview tunnel is having issues with cookies not showing up properly. Both are running on the same Chrome window.

Here is a log of the output of nookies parseCookies on the online VM:

```
 parseCookies: {
   _ga: 'GA1.2.1085256177.1647300286',
   datadome: '1fVoqdSQ~INT7sqMQY0ndVZqrTbBCNaJf~ItJbE6yIhwL-8WH9mfPoxZ_jiwbM3DUYv9u29OM5Yx6O7ZY3zwfqadHO~cNLFqZ_YQ1g4965xDI3m3GVnUbtIkw5P_rbk',
   iter_id: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhaWQiOiI2MjdkMmEwMzAwMjEyMTAwMDEwNzk5OWUiLCJjb21wYW55X2lkIjoiNWMwOThiM2QxNjU0YzEwMDAxMmM2OGY5IiwiaWF0IjoxNjUyMzY5OTIzfQ.KdiqglJiJjtLtRO9L576BUKs-fg43DTzdYUHqUFR3r8',
   myapp_cookiename: 'Fe26.2*1*f528c912c3b46422d19dff9bda87a9a8ab547b844361438efb7b9c2317e9f679*YTfsNWYiiHxYDtZKPU0dvQ*iaoaUkOk0dMw-8DaODb8g_4cdYFP79pcMwUw4F6DejgOIZ2sC8h3BVBXnapqrBnStetK3frQT5h-jNPRC9wmmKlm2zNKanIB1jj3He8xsAxIcalVR25hQbJ4LF8Mqok6*1654798779075*e36e579db8bc009c63dc848ef0e830964a8191a63238e63ab927b9a35196624f*KhoDT3sxxdx0_9Dhbu0BzmWhmP5vVXlDgUrGFftTdEM',
   user: 'test@gmail.com'
 }
```

And here is the same log on the Preview Tunnel VM:

```
parseCookies: {
   '__Host-previewc9corsvfs_9c0iPk6fDhrA1u2G': '9cZMuDF19mbjlZ0DVH7JnPD1ikuZvsdA',
   AWSALBCORS: '4mS8P/visPkg+aiOETBzvX14hTOXMkzQ+qDNJZwHbpgmU+xqPeUKhZp8d7W9hfIH+i6fQ+gpHx9yJ4wy/ZTlSHp0zAE0m5OOlpfO20pkaaWHG9Vhb4hb1KdY9kzN'
 }
```

I'm new to this interface so I'm not sure what more I'd need to provide for context. Overall, is anyone aware of Cloud9 Preview messing with cookies, and if so, is there a pattern to the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to this problem. It seems that using the preview window that appears in Cloud9 can cause issues. When I pop-out the window so that it appears in another tab, everything works fine.